# How to get the "raw" ptr of a lambda *capture* function

Tags: c++, assembly, reverse-engineering

I want to make a C++ assembly hooking using lambda captures but for this i need to get the pointer of a lambda **capture** function.

something like this:

```cpp
int val0 = 42;
auto lambdaCap = new auto([&]() -> int { return val0++; });
uint64_t pLambdaFn = static_cast<uint64_t>(&decltype(*lambdaCap)::operator()); // need this
```

I understand than a lambda function capture seems like an instance of class with a functor, but i want get the static address of lambda::operator().  In memory "lambdaCap" is just a ptr to the variables members used in the lambda.

Thanks

Comment: You may not be able to store a pointer to a member function in a normal pointer (the size of member pointers may be larger than normal pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&decltype(*lambdaCap)::operator())` is not valid because `decltype(*lambdaCap)` is actually an lvalue reference to the closure type.

Instead, `std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(lambdaCap)>` would give you the closure type itself. So you can write `&std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(lambdaCap)>::operator()` to get the pointer-to-member-function corresponding to the closure type's function call operator.

However, this expression has type `int (T::*)()`, which cannot be converted into an integer type. You can store it as-is, and call it using a pointer to an instance of the closure type (such as `lambdaCap` itself) but you can't convert it to `uint64_t`. There is no way to convert a pointer-to-nonstatic-member to an integer type, whether with `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` or any other cast.

Comment: Thanks! combine like this
```auto pLambdaFn = &std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(lambdaCap)>::operator();
uint64 lambdaFnAddr = *(uint64*)&pLambdaFn;```
It works fine to get the raw address on MSVC x64 (ptr cast maybe unsafe on others compilers/settings)

Comment: @LowelSassi I don't know what you mean by "the raw address" but if you figured out how to get a value that is useful for you, I am happy to have helped.